# How to retrieve folder with google drive service

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to retrieve a folder with Google drive Service.
The first problem is that I do not know the folder Id. I only know the folder name that is in my drive.

The second problem is that I only find this snippet of code for downloading file and not folder https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Here is the beginning of my code, but it does not work :(

```
session_start();

define( 'GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID', '422321818234bg877v326qtojhcsgsqr6p7fd563jmmh.apps.googleusercontent.com' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET', '1V5ADb4CpMZZqdSHfsORWro1' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_REDIRECT_URIS', 'http://localhost/drive.php' ); 

define( 'GDRIVE_SCOPE_01', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_SCOPE_02', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_SCOPE_03', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_SCOPE_04', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_SCOPE_05', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly' ); 
define( 'GDRIVE_FILE_KEY', 'https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_S8U3a8QeR_cUlCRTBLOWxiUnc&usp=sharing' ); 

$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setClientId( GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID ); 
$client->setClientSecret( GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET ); 
$client->setRedirectUri( GDRIVE_REDIRECT_URIS ); 
$client->setScopes( array( GDRIVE_SCOPE_01, GDRIVE_SCOPE_02, GDRIVE_SCOPE_03, GDRIVE_SCOPE_04, GDRIVE_SCOPE_05 ) ); 


if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit();
}

try { 
  $file = $service->files->get( GDRIVE_FILE_KEY ); 
  echo "Title: ", $file->getTitle(); 
  echo "Description: ", $file->getDescription(); 
  echo "MIME type: ", $file->getMimeType(); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
  echo "An error occurred: ", $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. "it does not work" is not a good way to get your problems fixed. The standard approach is to define precisely what you expected to see, and what you actually saw (eg. any error messages). When debugging Drive, it's very useful to capture the http traffic and paste that into your question. Nobody likes reading code. Also, try to avoid asking multiple questions. Break your problems down into the smallest, most precise, snippets and post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

"The first probleme is that I do not know the folder Id. I only know the folder name that is in my drive."

Do a files.list with a query containing the file name. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list and https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters